# How do I validate a serialize binary tree?

Tags: serialization, binary-tree

I have a string which contains serialization of binary tree. The serialization has been done using preorder. How do I check whether the given string is valid serialization or not ?

eg:

A B * * *

valid               Tree will

```
                                       A
                                     /   \
                                    B    NULL 
                                  /  \ 
                               NULL  NULL
```

A * B * * *           invalid

A * * B * *           invalid

Is this code good enough to validate

```
    Node *MakeTree(char *s)
    {
       if(!s)
         return NULL;

       if(*s=='*')
         return NULL;

       Node *root = newNode(*s);
       s++;
       root->left = MakeTree(s);
       root->right = MakeTree(s);
       return root;
    }

  bool IsValid(char *s)
  {

   if(!MakeTree(s))
      cout<<"Invalid";
   else
      cout<<"Valid";
  }
```

Comment: Just try to turn it back into a tree. In both the invalid cases you give you end up with a node and nowhere to put it.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated with code, would you please take a look ?

Comment: if the serialization was done using pre-order traversal, then it would be correct unless your implementation of pre-order traversal is wrong. So the question you really are asking is `is my pre-order traversal implementation correct?`

Comment: Well... not exactly, I wrote the code after @EJP's comment.